# Javascript: Event when DOM manupulation is done

Tags: javascript, watin

We have a table that is populated via an Ajax call. In our Watin tests, we want to check the contents of this table. We already managed to find out when the javascript populating the table has stopped running, so that part works fine.
However, in IE there seems to be a delay between the moment javascript populating the DOM is finished and the moment the DOM is complely updated for Watin to detect the changes.

Right now we have a `Thread.Sleep(500)` to make this work, but I don't like this. Is there an event or something to catch the moment the DOM is completely updated?

EDIT: Example code

```
var tbody = $("#myID tbody");
tbody.empty();
$.each(item.Producten, function (i, item) {
    var row = "<tr><td>" + item.Property + "</td></tr>";
    tbody.append(row);
});
```

Comment: Can you include some example code to demonstrate how you are adding the new content in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is such an event. If it were, WatiN would have use it. But when WatiN waits for something, eg. when you use `WaitUntil` methods (sometimes you could use it indirectly, for example when reading `Exists` property), WatiN is just making the `Thread.Sleep` call in a loop (see `TryFuncUntilTimeOut` class).

Almost everything you need can be achieved by using `WaitUntil` methods, but sometimes it is really tricky. If I were you, I would try a little bit more with this approach (especially if you are new to WatiN), but if it takes too much times I would just use `Thread.Sleep(500)` and forget about it.

I would like to add, that if there is a possibility to add some javascript code for test purposes to the end of your example code, you could set some kind of flag, like `loadingCompleted = 1`, and use `TryFuncUntilTimeOut` (I can't remember if there is appropriate `WaitUntil` method) to wait until `loadingCompleted` is set to 1. You can of course use WatiN to read this variable - see `Document.Eval` method.

Comment: Good suggestions, but sadly, none of them worked. Had to go with `Thread.Sleep(2500)`...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the Method `.WaitUntilExist` ?

EDIT: add sample code

In your JS you can add a class:

```
var tbody = $("#myID tbody");
tbody.empty();
$.each(item.Producten, function (i, item) {
    var row = "<tr class='newRow'><td>" + item.Property + "</td></tr>";
    tbody.append(row);
});
```

In WatiN side:

```
Table table = Browser.Table("myID");
table.OwnTableRow(Find.ByClass("newRow")).WaitUntilExists();
```

Remarks:

- If your table is empty, you can use `Find.Any` in the constraints
- If `Find.ByClass` doesn't work (I know it has some problems), use another specific constraint : `Find.ByIndex`, `Find.ById`, etc.

Comment: Sadly, no, because we add rows to the tablebody (see code added to the question)

Comment: Thought about that, but there are always rows in the table. There is no real hook for me to see if the new rows have been added to the table. What I am looking for is some event from the client side that I can listen to, signalling that IE is done updating the dom

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer along the same line as prostynick suggests.

Why not give the tbody an attribute like data-uniqueId and give that a different value everytime at the end of your javascript code. It might be as simple as being the current datetime, as long as it is different from previous values.

Now that you have this attribute and value you can use that in WatiN:

```
var currentUniqueId = browser.Table("myID").TableBody.GetAttributeValue("data-uniqueId");
.... do something to trigger the AJAX call

browser.Table("myID").TableBody.WaitUntil(!Find.By("data-uniqueId", currentUniqueId);
```

In the first line we retrieve the value for data-uniqueId. In the last line WatiN waits until there is no tbody with this attribute having that value (because the data-uniqueId value was changed by your javascript code). Now we can proceed.

HTH,
Jeroen